# Order by 1 shortens the result set to one row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, order-by

I'm running the following query:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) = N''
SELECT @sql += N' EXEC dbo.DoSomething @Tablename = ''' + SCHEMA_NAME(T.schema_id) + N'.' + T.name + N''''
--SELECT * 
FROM sys.tables T
INNER JOIN sys.indexes I ON I.object_id = T.object_id
ORDER by 1 
PRINT  @sql
```

But I'm only getting one line printed.
If I take out the `ORDER by 1` line, or replace it with

 `ORDER BY t.name` then I get the expected result.

Is this a bug in SQL Server?
I've tried it on SQL SErver 2016 SP1 and 2014 Sp2-Cu1.

Comment: `ORDER BY 1` and `ORDER BY t.name` do not do the same thing.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ; I know that, but not that it affected the number of rows in my "Result Set"

Comment: Yes, normally it should't affect. The problem here is a circular reference. The result of column 1 (`@sql`) is affected by the `ORDER BY` and the `ORDER BY` is affected by  column 1. That's one reason why Martin (and the KB article) has in his answer that *"The correct behavior for an aggregate concatenation query is **undefined**."*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this a bug in SQL Server?

No.

From [PRB: Execution Plan and Results of Aggregate Concatenation Queries Depend Upon Expression Location](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/287515)

> The correct behavior for an aggregate concatenation query is
> undefined.

See also this excellent answer by [Martin Smith](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3690/martin-smith) over at stackoverflow.
[nvarchar concatenation / index / nvarchar(max) inexplicable behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138593/nvarchar-concatenation-index-nvarcharmax-inexplicable-behavior/15163136#15163136)

Sometimes it works and sometimes it does not work and that is dependent on the execution plan. The magic works if the compute scalar doing the concatenation is positioned as the first operator below the select operator.

```
declare @T table(Name nvarchar(5));
insert into @T values (N'aaaa3'),(N'bbbb2'),(N'cccc1');
declare @S nvarchar(18) = N'';

select @S += ',' + T.Name
from @T as T;
```

[image]

But if you are unlucky you could end up with a different plan. This one has a sort operator between the select and the compute scalar.

```
select @S += ',' + T.Name
from @T as T
order by reverse(T.Name);
```

[image]

The best way to solve this (in my opinion) is to use `for xml path` to do the concatenation instead.

```
select @S  = (
             select ',' + T.Name 
             from @T as T
             order by reverse(T.Name)
             for xml path(''), type
             ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');
```

Some version of SQL Server in the future will have a built in string aggregate function [STRING_AGG (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt790580.aspx).